# Loading Stylesheets in an embeddable javascript code.

Tags: javascript, css

So I built a widget that embeds into my clients website with some JS. The code that's being rendered requires some css so it looks and functions properly on the website. How should I go about including thse stylesheet and have it work with the code inside the javascript?

```
<div id="widget"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var sp = document.createElement('script'); sp.type = 'text/javascript'; sp.async = true;
    sp.src = 'http://example.com/widget/widget.js?key=248572180ede986058ede3519a25665e&r='+(new Date().getTime());
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(sp, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: Go with a style tag instead of a link if you have a few styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a way you can add a stylesheet to your head tag:

```
head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.rel = 'stylesheet';
link.href = ""; // css link goes here
head.appendChild(link);
```

or you can create a style tag:

```
var css = ''; //put your css in here
head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
style = document.createElement('style');

style.type = 'text/css';
if (style.styleSheet){
   style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
   style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}

head.appendChild(style);
```